How to load user roles from Database and assign to user in blazor wasm
I have a Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) app hosted in ASP.NET Core that authenticates users using default ASP.NET Core Identity.
In the server project in Program.cs, I have this code:
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "0123456789";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
}).AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
  .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DBcontext>().AddDefaultUI();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<AppUser, DBcontext>();

And in the client project (wasm) in Program.cs I wrote this:
builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

I added some roles like Admin, User, ... to register user by UserManager or DbContext.
After registering
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IdentityResult> AddRole(AppUser user, string RoleName)
{
    try
    {
        var Role = await db.Roles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Name == RoleName);

        if (Role == null)
        {
            Role = new IdentityRole()
                       { 
                           Name = RoleName, 
                           NormalizedName = RoleName.ToUpper() 
                       };
            await db.Roles.AddAsync(Role);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return await um.AddToRoleAsync(user, RoleName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ....
    }
}

and the roles are added to the database correctly.
In the AuthorizeView tag, I wrote this:
<AuthorizeView Roles="Admin,User,Owner">

but after login of a user, this tag's children are not displayed

What version of .net is your project using? Have you tried using a single role for authentication? And did you receive any related error messages?

I'm using .Net6 in this project

After my test, you can create a custom user factory in the Client application, and you need to manually enable role declaration. Here is an example for your reference:
In the database, I added and bound the role information of an account:


In my client, I configured a CustomUserFactory, which inherits AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory, which is used to create a ClaimsPrincipal object, contains the user's identity information and claims:
public class CustomUserFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor)
    : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>(accessor)
{
    public override async ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(
        RemoteUserAccount account,
        RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
    {
        var user = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

        if (user.Identity is not null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity;
            var roleClaims = identity.FindAll(identity.RoleClaimType).ToArray();

            if (roleClaims.Any())
            {
                foreach (var existingClaim in roleClaims)
                {
                    identity.RemoveClaim(existingClaim);
                }

                var rolesElem =
                    account.AdditionalProperties[identity.RoleClaimType];

                if (options.RoleClaim is not null && rolesElem is JsonElement roles)
                {
                    if (roles.ValueKind == JsonValueKind.Array)
                    {
                        foreach (var role in roles.EnumerateArray())
                        {
                            var roleValue = role.GetString();

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(roleValue))
                            {
                                identity.AddClaim(
                                  new Claim(options.RoleClaim, roleValue));
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var roleValue = roles.GetString();

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(roleValue))
                        {
                            identity.AddClaim(
                              new Claim(options.RoleClaim, roleValue));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return user;
    }
}

Then in the Client application, register the factory in the Program file and add role-related services:
builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "role";
}).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserFactory>();

In the Server application:
Configure the Identity server：
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
        options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
    });

After I successfully log in and visit the Test page for configuring authorization:
@page "/Test"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization

<AuthorizeView Roles="Admin,User,Owner">
    <Authorized>
        <h3>Welcome, authorized user!</h3>
        <p>You have access to this content because you are in one of the following roles: Admin, User, or Owner.</p>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <h3>Access Denied</h3>
        <p>You do not have permission to view this content.</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {
   
}


For more information, you can refer to this document
